# Import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting a Swift compiler error as:

```
Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied.
```

I have re-installed my Xcode, still the issue exists and in another user account, Xcode builds the project without any compilation error.

Comment: Are you sure that the user installing Xcode has sufficient rights? It sounds like an issue with user access rights, and not Xcode as such...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258264/opening-import-file-for-module-swift-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

That has probably something with your frameworks, try adding them again, or if you are using Carthage, make sure not to do `Carthage update` with `sudo`.

Comment: This right here! My problem was that I was using sudo... I been stuck on this for a while. Thanks!