# Opening import file for module 'CoreData': Permission denied

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, core-data

For some days, I have a problem of "Persmission denied" when I build a project :

```
<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'CoreData': Permission denied
```

I build on Xcode 7.2 with IOS 7.1 as target.

I get the project from GIT and no others members of my team have had this issue.

There are some others questions with the same type of error : [Opening import file for module 'Swift' Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196440/opening-import-file-for-module-swift-permission-denied)

but the answer not respond to my issue. I have checked the Framework Search Paths and there are good. There are not looking in the wrong location for my framework.

I packaged my Project folder and try to build on other session of my macBook and on other macBook too and i didn't have the problem.

So I don't understand what is wrong. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure, but for that kind of error I'd probably delete and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I delete and reinstall Xcode but nothing change...